# Cauchy's integral question

Tags: complex-analysis

My definition of the theorem is stated in [this section of the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem).

My question is why point $a$ must be within the interior of $D$, and can't it also be in $U$ (where I mean the part of $U$ but not $D$ the domain where $f$ is analytic)(I think $D$ is smaller since $D$ is any simple closed contour lying entirely within $U$)?

Comment: By being in the interior of D it is already in U since $D\subset U$... what exactly are you asking?

Comment: i mean isn't the graph of u is bigger than D and point a could be in u but not in D ?

Comment: @ dylan moreland,what do you mean by a is in in U∖∂D

Comment: @dylan moreland-may you answer my question or give me some example in your example?

Comment: $U$ is a superset of $D$... yes. $f$ is holomorphic on the open set $U$. Suppose $a$ is a point within $U$, then you can form a tiny circle around $a$ contained still within $U$ so that you can apply the integral formula to evaluate $f(z)/(z-a)$, where the contour is exactly that circle within which $a$ is contained.

Comment: i am really confused-isn't the contour is just f(z)?

Comment: @Victor: I suggest you brush up on some of the prereqs of studying functions of a complex variable before trying to understand this theorem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a$ is not in $D$, then $f(z)/(z-a)$ is holomorphic in $D$.  So the integral around the boundary of $D$ (the contour) is equal $0$ by [Cauchy's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).